# Accessing cpp #define pre-processor variable in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

i have a define say

```
#define VERSION 2019.1
```

this is defined in a `.h` file. I want to access the VERSION inside a shell script ? How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple `awk`:

```
ver=$(awk '$2 == "VERSION" {print $3}' file.h)
echo "$ver"
```

```
2019.1
```